# Android : ColorPrimaryDark not found while building app

Tags: android, gradle

I declared in the ressources file "colors.xml" a color named "ColorPrimaryDark". Now I don't need it anymore so I would like to delete it. But if I do so, Android Studio cannot build my app anymore, although I'm using this color nowhere.

Build output :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     com.mycompany.myapp.app-mergeDebugResources-29:/values/values.xml:2154: error: resource color/ColorPrimaryDark (aka com.mycompany.myapp:color/ColorPrimaryDark) not found.
     com.mycompany.myapp.app-mergeDebugResources-29:/values/values.xml:2154: error: resource color/ColorPrimaryDark (aka com.mycompany.myapp:color/ColorPrimaryDark) not found.
     error: failed linking references.
```

I tried unsuccesfully to find the file "com.mycompany.myapp.app-mergeDebugResources-29:/values/values.xml" if it exists. I also tried to recreate the project and copy-paste only the necessary java and xml in the new project, so that other files are resetted, but the problem remains.